# PostgreSQL / NodeJS: Query Result Empty

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have a query which returns 0 rows but executing the same query using pgadmin or dbeaver returns a result set with rows.

**Ive noticed this because i have a postgresql function which should return rows but didnt. After that i started debugging.**

Other queries are not affected.
I tried it using knexjs (`knex.raw()`) and pg (`client.query()`).

Off cause, i checked the connection a dozen times using different queries and reading the connection string.

This is really strange.

### The whole point here is, why does this work in dbeaver and not in my code. Is this a drivers thing?

#### Queries

```
select id from (
    select id, started_at from queue 
    where finished_at is null and started_at is not null order by id
) d 
where date_part('minute',age(now(), started_at)) >= 5
```

I played around a lot and found that the following queries do work.

```
select id from queue 
where date_part('minute',age(now(), started_at)) >= 5;
```

and

```
select id from (
    select id, started_at from queue 
    where finished_at is null and started_at is not null order by id
) d;
```

### Update

#### not working

```
const test = await this.knexInstance.raw(`
    select id from (
        select id, started_at from queue 
        where finished_at is null and started_at is not null order by id
    ) d 
    where date_part('minute',age(now(), started_at)) >= 5
`);
console.log(test.rows); // => []
console.log(test.rows.length); // => 0
```

#### working

```
const test = await this.knexInstance.raw(`
    select id from queue 
    where date_part('minute',age(now(), started_at)) >= 5;
`);
console.log(test.rows); // => Array(48083) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, …]
console.log(test.rows.length); // => 48083
```

Comment: can you post the node.js code snippet as well?

Comment: It looks your  code returns response early, whereas the actual response from Database comes late. May be you need to put callback function in there, that execute after the result returned from DB.

Comment: i post some nodejs code in a second.

Comment: my question is updated. Thx!

Comment: Try to write your query without nesting. Does it work that way?

Comment: It does. But why?

Comment: I guess it's magic. But being serious, I can't figure it out yet. A very strange case. I'll try to give a second look on it later.

Comment: Please include knex version you are using. Also I'm 99.9% sure that knex is not the reason why query is not returning results. That sql is passed pretty much directly to pg driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I tried to reproduce this, but got result as expected. I'm using `knex@0.14.4`.

```
const knex = require('knex')(config)

async function main () {
    await knex.raw('create table queue ( id bigserial primary key, started_at timestamp with time zone not null default current_timestamp, finished_at timestamp with time zone);')
    await knex('queue').insert({ started_at: knex.raw('now() - \'10 minutes\'::interval'), finished_at: null })
    await knex('queue').insert({ started_at: knex.raw('now() - \'11 minutes\'::interval'), finished_at: null })
    await knex('queue').insert({ started_at: knex.raw('now() - \'12 minutes\'::interval'), finished_at: null })
    await knex('queue').insert({ started_at: knex.raw('now() - \'13 minutes\'::interval'), finished_at: null })

    await knex('queue').insert({ started_at: knex.raw('now() - \'4 minutes\'::interval'), finished_at: null })
    const test = await knex.raw(`
    select id from (
        select id, started_at from queue
        where finished_at is null and started_at is not null order by id
    ) d
    where date_part('minute',age(now(), started_at)) >= 5
`);
    console.log(test.rows) // Array(4)
    console.log(test.rows.length) // => 4 
    await knex.raw('drop table queue;') 
    await knex.destroy()
}

main()
```

All I can recommend is to try to run this example locally and watch the results. And try to upgrade knex to the latest version (if it's not).

Answer (score 1):

Why directly using raw?

```
const test = await this.knexInstance.select('queue')
             .columns(['id'])
             .whereRaw('date_part('minute',age(now(), started_at)) >= 5');
```

I'm have less idea about PostgreSQL but it should work.